# Twitter Hovercards in GWT PagingScrollTable

Tags: javascript, gwt, twitter, javascript-framework, twitter-anywhere

How do you implement Twitter Hovercards in GWT PagingScrollTable?

The Hovercard links work fine when, say, I add `new Label("@ded")` to a HorizontalPanel.  However the Twitter JavaScript function doesn't seem to apply when I put "@ded" into a PagingScrollTable row.

I'm a JavaScript newbie.

In response to Igor's request, here's some more details.  According to the Twitter [docs](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin) I put a couple of scripts into the `<head>` of my HTML file:

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=myId&v=1"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Twitter @Anywhere Hovercards -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    twttr.anywhere(function (T) {
        T.hovercards();
    });
</script>
```

Then the Hovercards work as described above, except in a GWT PagingScrollTable.  For example, I've implemented an `AbstractColumnDefinition` whose `getCellValue()` method returns "@ded".  The "@ded" appears in the table, but it doesn't seem to be recognized by the scripts---the "ded" part is not underlined as it is outside the table (the [Twitter doc](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin) shows an example of working Hovercards).

Looking at it with a web inspector, I see that `new Label("@ded")` appears as

```
<div class="gwt-Label">
    "@"
    <a class="twitter-anywhere-user" href="http://twitter.com/ded">ded</a>
</div>
```

but in the last row of my table I see

```
        <tr style="background:#fafafa;" class>
            <td class>@ded</td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And I've found an error in the logs when I page the table and try to invoke the second script as JSNI, *but only when the rows are loaded from cached data*:

```
04:15:51.280 [ERROR] Uncaught exception escaped
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (ReferenceError): Can't find variable: twttr  
 line: 3  
 sourceId: 4675433328  
 expressionBeginOffset: 209  
 expressionCaretOffset: 214  
 expressionEndOffset: 214   
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:195)    
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:120)
    ...
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Maybe a screenshot of both situations and some source code?

Comment: I've added some details.

Comment: Interesingly, the demos don't work in Opera ;) Anyway, is that the precise output of your last row of your table? Because there shouldn't be any "alone" `class` attributes. As for the exception (Can't find variable: twttr) - when is it thrown? Always? Or only when you use the PagingScrollTable? And I presume you put Twitter's JS code only in your host HTML page? (and not in your UiBinder templates, etc)

Comment: As Igor asked, does this work outside of PagingScrollTable?

Comment: @Igor Yes, the solitary "class" looks odd, but that seems to be the way the Safari Web Inspector displays an empty value; in FireBug you see <td class="">@ded</td>.  The two scripts are in the <head> of my single HTML page.  I'm not using UiBinder.

Comment: @Arthur: I noted in the second paragraph that the Hovercards work in a Label in a HorizontalPanel (which is an HTML table), and I gave the view of the working tag from Web Inspector in the second code block above.  I also checked that they work in a <table> in the HTML file.

Comment: @Igor Your question about when the Exception is thrown is a good one.  It is only thrown when the table is loaded with cached data (for those who don't know, PagingScrollTable uses a CachedTableModel that stores rows before and after the visible rows), not when new rows are downloaded.

Comment: The `Can't find variable: twttr` exception would point to problems with the way GWT handles JSNI (not that you are using it here) - you have to reference the host HTML page via `$wnd` because GWT's code is run in a iframe (to prevent namespace clashes). I'm not a JS expert (that's why I chose GWT ;)) and it's a long shot, but try with `$wnd.T.hovercards();` - maybe `PagingScrollTable` does some crazy stuff behind the scenes ;) Also, what happens if you dynamically add a `Label` (or something similar that works for you) - does it get its hovercard?

Comment: @Igor:  The Label in the HorizontalPanel mentioned in the second paragraph is dynamically added and works fine.  Having worked with PagingScrollTable for a while, I can confirm that it does crazy stuff; I haven't figured out this particular crazy stuff, yet.  Unfortunately, $wnd.T.hovercards() makes no difference.

Comment: Eh, I meant `$wnd.twttr.anywhere`. But either way, I remember someone from the GWT team mentioning on one of the GWT presentations on Google IO that the `PagingScrollTable` was full of bugs and more of a "testing field" then a production ready widget. Have you tried the new data presentation widgets in GWT 2.1? (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/ReleaseNotes.html) I don't know at which stage they are atm, but there are samples available - maybe it's worth investigating, since it's unlikely that `PagingScrollTable` will be further developed.